# linux get_user function unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to implement a one-byte char device driver for the linux kernel, as part of my operating system module assignment. To implement the device driver, I have to define the read and write function. Below is my device write function

```
ssize_t onebyte_write(struct file *filep, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    if (get_user(*onebyte_data, buf) != 0)
        return 0;
    if (count > 1)
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: No space left on device\n");
    return 1;
}
```

'onebyte_data' is a char pointer to a dynamically allocated one byte memory in the kernel space. From my understanding, 'get_user' is supposed to copy a simple variable (int or char) from user space to kernel space. But when I execute the following set of command

```
printf abc > /dev/onebyte
cat /dev/onebyte
```

The result is a 'c' instead of a 'a', meaning get_user has read the whole input string instead of just the first character, and store the last character 'c' instead. Is this the expected behaviour? What should I do if I just want to store the first character of the input in onebyte_data?

Comment: create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). if your `onebyte_data` belongs there, then make an edit and show it. from what i've understood you're passing an `int` value to a function that expects a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> The result is a 'c' instead of a 'a', meaning `get_user` has read the whole input string...

No. That means your `.write` function is **called several times**. And 'c' is a character written on the last call.

---

Most of user-space utilities which write files do that at **high level**. They may call `.write` function (via `write` syscall) several times. This depends on the **return value** of `.write` function:

- `n < 0` means that `.write` has finished with an **error**. No more `.write` is called.
- `n = count` means that `.write` has processed **all bytes** passed to it. No more `.write` is called.
- `0 <= n < count` means that `.write` has processed only the **first** `n` **bytes** passed to it. The call to `.write` will be **repeated** for remaining bytes.

Note, that high-level user space functions are allowed to divide input string into **several chunks**, and pass only a single chunk to the `.write` at a time. In that case `.write` function will be called repeatedly until it writes all bytes from the last chunk (or returns an error indicator).

---

On success you return 1, meaning that your `.write` function processes only a **single byte**. So the function is called for the remaining bytes (with `count` reduces by 1). Only when your `.write` function is called for the last byte no more calls are followed. This is because the return value (1) is equal to the number of bytes passed to the function.

> What should I do if I just want to **store the first character** of the input in onebyte_data?

First character is the one at offset 0. So you need to store only the character when `*f_pos` is 0. All other characters should be **ignored**, that is you need to return `count`.

```
ssize_t onebyte_write(struct file *filep, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    if (*f_pos == 0) {
      // Need to store the first character.
      if (get_user(*onebyte_data, buf) != 0)
          return -EFAULT; // This is how an error should be signalled in `.write` function.
    }

    // We will return `count` for ignore all (other) characters.
    //
    // Before that we need to update `f_pos` parameter
    // to point after the bytes "written" (actually, ignored).
    *f_pos += count;

    return count;
}
```

---

Since your function always return number of bytes passed to it, you may omit updating `f_pos` argument:

```
ssize_t onebyte_write(struct file *filep, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    if (*f_pos == 0) {
      // Need to store the first character.
      if (get_user(*onebyte_data, buf) != 0)
          return -EFAULT; // This is how an error should be signalled in `.write` function.
    }
    return count;
}
```

Such change won't affect on writting to the file via `echo` or `printf`:

```
# printf abcd > /dev/onebyte
# cat /dev/onebyte
a
```

This is because `echo` doesn't actually split small input strings into chunks, so your write function will be called only **once**.

The things would change when using `dd` utility:

```
# printf abcd | dd bs=2 count=2 of=/dev/onebyte
# cat /dev/onebyte
c
```

That time `dd` calls `.write` function exactly **twice**, the first time passing `ab` to it, and the second time - `cd`.

Because you don't change `f_pos` after the first call, the second call will also have `f_pos` equal to 0, so you will store the first byte passed to that call.